# pam_cracklib setting min password length

Tags: password, pam, cracklib

I am experimenting with PAM and, in particular, pam_cracklib at the moment. I've run into a bit of a problem setting min password length and credit for particular character types. My config file for `passwd` currently reads

`password required pam_cracklib.so minlen=3 lcredit=3`

and originally I had

`password required pam_cracklib.so minlen=3`

Neither allowed me to enter a three (or four or five or six) character password of any kind (let alone all lower case characters) and allows told me the password was too short.

`BAD PASSWORD: it is WAY too short`

I have yet to find an answer elsewhere/in documentation. What's going on?

**Update:**
I am running Ubuntu 18.04

The lines above are everything in the configuration file in `pam.d` for `passwd`

I have tried this on separate machines with the same result. Both running 18.04 but I don't think it's specific to any particular configuration.

Comment: I am not. Is that a special case?

Comment: Same result. Didn't like any short password I entered.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't read the documentation carefully enough.

> The minimum acceptable size for the new password (plus one if
>              credits are not disabled which is the default). In addition to
>              the number of characters in the new password, credit (of +1 in
>              length) is given for each different kind of character (other,
>              upper, lower and digit). The default for this parameter is 9
>              which is good for a old style UNIX password all of the same type
>              of character but may be too low to exploit the added security of
>              a md5 system. Note that there is a pair of length limits in
>              Cracklib itself, a "way too short" limit of 4 which is hard coded
>              in and a defined limit (6) that will be checked without reference
>              to minlen. If you want to allow passwords as short as 5
>              characters you should not use this module.

I was trying to bypass hard-coded limits.